# Problem in downloading Torrent file with Transmission Bit Torrent

Tags: files, downloads, bittorrent

I am pretty new in Ubuntu. I have just installed Desktop version of Ubuntu 14.4.3 LTS on my Laptop. My installation was successful. I have Transmission Bit Torrent Client on my Ubuntu now.

When I tried to download a torrent file, Tranmission window will open but nothing has been downloaded.
I get this message: `Downloading metadata from 0 peers (0% done )`
Also, when I go to Tracker, I see several links with `Connection failed`
here is one error message:
`udp://open.demonn.com:1337 Got an error " Connection failed" ... Minutes ago`
and several udp links like that.
I went to Ubuntu Software Center. Uninstalled , and re-installed Transmission Bit Torrent again, but still have the same issue. 
Its version is: transmission-gtk 2.82-1.1ubuntu3.1

*How can I fix this issue?*

Comment: This will be what you see when a torrent is dead, so you will encounter torrents like this in normal operation. Are you sure you have a problem, cq are you sure the torrent file should work?

Comment: This can be caused by a bad torrent as well. Cross-check it with more torrents.

Comment: Hi Requist, I am sure the torrent file is correct. I tried to download several small size file, but I got the same result. I could download these files from windows. Transmission bit torrent on my ubuntu does not work. Is ther any way to fix it?

Comment: Check that your modem/router's firewall is open for transmission/bittorrent port [and it forwards/redirects to the correct machine on the local LAN].  Also, check the linux firewall.  Meander around transmission.  There is an option to select [and test] the port.

Comment: Hi Craig Estey, I run command " sudo ufw status" status was "inactive".

Comment: I have just installed ubuntu LTS, and I have not set up any other firewall yet. Also, I have to look for any way to check modem/router firewall

Comment: You were right. It was my router setting. I fixed it. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this torrent can't reach any peers. Either because there are no peers available or the trackers are down (momentarily or forever). This has nothing to do with transmission. It's just that torrent you're trying to download.